# How to resolve issue... Amazon ec2, elastic IP setup with Route 53 not working?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, amazon-route53, a-record

In this post it says its best to use CNAME only for Ec2 / route 53 setup:
[EC2/Route53: How do I assign my new domain name to an instance?](https://serverfault.com/questions/363292/ec2-route53-how-do-i-assign-my-new-domain-name-to-an-instance).

However, I added:

```
*.mysite.org. CNAME ec2-174-129-38-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
```

...to my Route 53 DNS config and **www.**mysite.org works but mysite.org does not and the site 301's to non-www (mysite.org) so essentially nothing works.

Am I missing something? I guess I DO need an A record to the elastic IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need an A record. CNAMEs can't be used for the root record of a domain.

Comment: Added A record and its working. thx. So what is Eric reffering to here?: http://serverfault.com/a/363294/100787

Comment: Note that he's talking about `www.example.com`, not `example.com`.